# Text and its dropdown not in a single line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to put the text and its dropdown in a single row but not possible and i've tried using display:inline and display inline block.

If I am trying the same outside ( not in my code) it is working fine.
Can you suggest what could be the reason and what CSS can I apply to achieve the same.

```
Edge by: <select id="EdgeAlgorithm" onClick="UpdateMetricFromGUI()">
               <option value="Differential">Differential</option>
               <option value="Threshold">Threshold</option>
         </select>
```

The output is coming out as:

> Edge by:
>   (dropdown)

instead of:

> Edge by: (dropdown).

Comment: hard to tell without context, but my guess would be that these elements are within a parent element that isn't wide enough for both to fit side by side.

Comment: Please show your full code.. this works: http://jsfiddle.net/nJa45/

Comment: I'm guessing its like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nJa45/1/, in which case you'll probably want to restyle it making the parent larger

Comment: Find css for `select` element and post it in question.

Comment: there is no css for select element

Comment: the code is too big. I cannot post the code. And as I said it is working on fiddle or any other editor

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the CSS and what the two elements' container looks like, but if you `float: left` the `select` and put the text in a `label` or `span` and `float` that `left` it should work. You can then control the `width` of both from there too.

Again, it'd be great to see the actual the CSS you have going on.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to have a label with correct styling - and of course widths have to be OK (especially a parent which has to accomodate both of these elements in a line) but it would be something like this:

```
<label for="EdgeAlgorithm" style="float:left">Edge by:</label><select id="EdgeAlgorithm" onClick="UpdateMetricFromGUI()" style="float:left">
               <option value="Differential">Differential</option>
               <option value="Threshold">Threshold</option>
         </select>
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and its working the only problem is its not in a line. The dropdown is slightly up than the rest of the elements and in chrome it is coming on the top of text only.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just have to add padding-top to the label style and put in correct px value - it depends on the font size you're using, on the padding you may have in the select element itself and so on. This will move the label text a bit "down" and this way you center it with the text in the select element.

`<label for="EdgeAlgorithm" style="float:left; padding-top: 2px;">`